# Open a URL within code in PHP

Tags: php, file, url, curl

I want to open a URL within php code.

```
http://www.vendorsite.com/bulksms/bulksms?username=xxx&password=xxx&msg=xxx
```

`file` and `file_get_contents` are throwing me errors as no http:// wrapper allowed and cURL is giving me no output and timing out.
I tested cURL on other URLs it works fine, its only this vendor URL which fails. It works fine on localhost but not on server. If i open the URL directly in browser it still works. Don't know why on the server it keeps timing out.

```
$live_url = "http://www.vendorsite.com:8080/bulksms/bulksms?username=xxx&password=xxx&msg=xxx";
$parse_url = url_get_contents ($live_url);

function url_get_contents ($url) {
    if (function_exists('curl_exec')){ 
        $conn = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,  true);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/plain")); 
        $url_get_contents_data = (curl_exec($conn));
        curl_close($conn);
    }elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        $url_get_contents_data = file_get_contents($url);
    }elseif(function_exists('fopen') && function_exists('stream_get_contents')){
        $handle = fopen ($url, "r");
        $url_get_contents_data = stream_get_contents($handle);
    }else{
        $url_get_contents_data = false;
    }
    return $url_get_contents_data;
}
```

`PHP Version 5.3.27`

It works on localhost but not on server

Comment: try setting a user agent for cURL, something like:
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

Comment: Didn't work :( the online version keeps timing out. I dont understand how its timing out.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Have you registered the server with the vendor site to allow connections from your server?

Comment: Yes, when i try from localhost, it works fine, when i open the vendor URL directly in the browser it works, but when try the same script on the server it fails

Comment: vendor smarter than you in stopping your stealing ways

Comment: No, vendor himself has given this way. His API reference file used file() function, I just replaced it with cURL thats it.

Comment: I fail to see why you are asking us instead of the vendor...

Comment: Its coz the URL works just fine. The all problem lies in my curl php code.